# Factoring a polynomial with 4 terms where factoring by grouping does not work?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Ok so I am instructed to factor $t^3 -10t^2 +27t -18$
However, factoring by grouping does not work in this case? 
I know I can guess and check via the rational zero theorem.  BUT THAT SEEMS SO TEDIOUS. Are there any other methods possible?

Comment: How about you try a *simple* rational root nevertheless? The simplest of all, maybe.

Comment: rational root? Can you please show me an example, I have never heard of this technique

Comment: [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) $\;\equiv\;$ your `rational zero theorem`.

Comment: WAIT are you refering to the rational zero theorem as I've mentioned in the post? LOL

Comment: The rational root theorem is very, very efficient.  But you could speed it up by sketching the graph and seeing, roughly, where the zeroes are.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that since it is so tedious

Comment: Tedious?  You can do this one visually.  Just try it.

Comment: @Prandals Give it a try. By the 2nd or 3rd equation you work out, you'll learn to instantly *recognize* when the coefficients add up to 0. It's not *that* complicated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we do not promise any way to avoid tedium

Comment: I think you could had found a root by the rational zero theorem in less time that it took you to ask the question ;)

Comment: You could always try [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+t^3-10t^2%2B27t-18)

Comment: The first thing I do is plug in 0 or $\pm 1$. In this example, it's not even much of a "rational root theorem", since the leading term clearly means that the roots should be integers if they exist. Once you actually start with small numbers you should get it fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in this case you'll hit the jackpot if you try $t=1$, the rational root theorem works well even if the smallest root would have large prime factors and would not come up a long time after the end of the universe when trying out the candidates one by one. To speed up the process, you should consider a change of variable after each negative result. E.g. substituting $t=-1$ yields -56. This means that substituting $t = u - 1$ and rewriting the polynomial in powers of $u$ will yield a constant term of $-56$. The roots in terms of $u$ must thus be divisors of $56 = 7*8$, In terms of $t$ these possible roots are thus of the form $\pm 2^n 7^m - 1$ with $0\leq n\leq 3$ and $0\leq m\leq 1$. But any root must also be a divisor of 18, this leaves you with the candidates:

$$t = -9,-3,-2,1,3,6$$

which is a considerably shorter list than the original list of all the divisors of 18.

Comment: +1 for an attempted serious answer to an otherwise borderline trolling question. Except $t=-1$ gives $-56$.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks,I'll correct the answer.

Comment: It's not a troll question, I am finding the roots so i can integrate | t^3-10t^2+27t-18 |

Comment: the function was originally the velocity function and I wish to integrate into displacement hence the absolute value.

Comment: mb not displacemant but total distance covered lol

Comment: @CountIblis Looks good now, and the technique is indeed handy at times.

Comment: @Prandals I did say "*borderline*" ;-) But seriously, it's obvious that the equation can't have negative real roots because of the alternating signs of the coefficients. That leaves the positive divisors of $18$ as potential rational root candidates. There is $6$ of them. The very first one to try would have worked.

Comment: @dxiv lol so if just actually attempted the rational zero theorem the first guess wouldve cleared